# Using declared variables in the where clause with Case When

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to use declared variables in my where clause to help set certain filters.

The idea is to pull data between certain dates dependent on a specified event date, but I want to filter out previous event dates from coming up in the results.

So for example, if I have 4 event dates, and I want to pull the week of data before that event date (excluding previous event dates) I'll have code like this (note the where clause is incorrect, but this is the idea of what I'm looking for):

EX:

```
/* 
Event Dates:
2021-07-20
2021-08-02
2021-08-04
2021-08-05
*/


DECLARE @event_date DATE = '2021-08-04', @start_date DATE, @end_date DATE 

if @event_date  = '2021-07-20' BEGIN SET @start_date = '2021-07-15' SET @end_date = '2021-07-20' END
else if @event_date = '2021-08-02' BEGIN SET @start_date = '2021-07-28' SET @end_date = '2021-08-02' END
else if @event_date = '2021-08-04' BEGIN SET @start_date = '2021-07-30' SET @end_date = '2021-08-04' END
else if @event_date = '2021-08-05' BEGIN SET @start_date = '2021-07-31' SET @end_date = '2021-08-05' END

SELECT acct_num, dt, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 /*dt column is the date*/
FROM TEST_DB 
WHERE dt BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date 
AND (CASE -- This is basically what I'm trying to accomplish, not sure how though
    WHEN @event_date = '2021-08-04' THEN dt!= '2021-08-02'
    WHEN @event_date = '2021-08-05' THEN dt not in ('2021-08-02', '2021-08-04')
END as whatever) 
AND acct_num = 1234
```

So ideally, when pulling date ranges that overlap with previous event dates - those event dates are excluded from the results. I found many other posts on SO, but nothing seemed to really answer this specific question.

Help is appreciated!

EDIT for clarification: Here's what the DB would look like. Var columns are just dummy data.

| acct_num | dt | var1 | var2 | var3 | var4 | var5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-07-29 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 1234 | 2021-07-30 | 7 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2021-07-31 | 6 | 4 | 7 | 2 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2021-08-01 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2021-08-02 | 6 | 5 | 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2021-08-03 | 1 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 1234 | 2021-08-04 | 7 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 0 |
| 1234 | 2021-08-05 | 6 | 4 | 7 | 2 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2021-08-06 | 2 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 4 |

So ideally, depending on which event_date variable I declare, I would like the results to be returned in the following fashion: EX, if I declare the event date as '2021-08-04', I would be looking for the the rows with dt '2021-07-30' through '2021-08-04' **excluding** the row with dt = '2021-08-02'.

Same would apply if the event_date was set to '2021-08-05', I would want the rows with dt between '2021-07-31' and '2021-08-31', **excluding** rows with dt = '2021-08-02' and 2021-08-04'.

Let me know if this helps or if more clarification is required.

Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) with real sample data and desired results based on multiple possible event dates, so we don't have to guess what's in `TEST_DB` or reverse engineer the word problem parts of your question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Super cool. I didn't know this was a thing - unfortunately, it's blocked by my company's firewall. I added an edit to show the DB contents. Hope this helps

Comment: can you please confirm if these exclusions are nominated and not logical? cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will need a table of date exclusions, in this case using `table variable`

Then make a full list based on range and making a `DERIVED TABLE`, using the derived table use `NOT EXISTS` to removed the excluded dates

```
declare @tableofexclusions table (maindate date,excludeddate date)

insert into @tableofexclusions
values ('2021-08-04','2021-08-02'),
('2021-08-05','2021-08-02'),
('2021-08-05','2021-08-04')

select * from ( -- generate list within the range
SELECT
  acct_num,
  dt,
  var1,
  var2,
  var3,
  var4,
  var5,
  @event_date eventdate
/*dt column is the date*/
FROM TEST_DB t1
WHERE dt BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date 
AND acct_num = 12345
) x
where 
not exists (  -- remove dates matching from tableofexclusions based on the event
select 1 from @tableofexclusions t2
where t2.maindate = x.eventdate
and t2.excludeddate = x.dt
)
```

Comment: Would this exclude the previously specified event_dates in the original WHERE clause?

Comment: did you test it? you are only after of the most recent event against the account number

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it did not work for me. The acct_nums that I needed excluded were still present in the results.

Comment: simply because your first version of OP did not have a clear explanation. i will revise my answer

Comment: @Mac, try the updated solution.